# Was Hemlock Grove's story line completed?

Tags: hemlock-grove

I am interested in watching Hemlock Grove on Netflix, I see that the show has ended. Was the story line is completed or did it just end (i.e. Firefly)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It came to a rational conclusion.

I won't say more than that, for fear of spoilers if you intend to watch it.  If your concern is that it will just end randomly without conclusion, you have nothing to worry about.